# The click event doesn't call when i add Linkbutton from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I use below code for add `LinkButton` in code behind but when i click on each link button the click event doesn't call but if i remove `if(!IsPostBack)` work properly

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.sr();
        }//if
    }

    void sr()
    {
        LinkButton lnk;
        for (int i =1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.ID="lnk"+i.ToString();
            lnk.Text = i.ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
            this.pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
 }
    }

    void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        lnk.Text = "Clicked";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a **linkButton** dynamically.

You have to call the sr() in the **Page_Init** function like...

```
void Page_Init(object Sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  sr();
}
```

[Please check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: if i recall `sr` in `Page_Init` my function call two times and create each LinkButton Two times

Comment: I remove it from page_Load and put it in Page_Init with ISPostBack but again have same problem

Comment: What i am saying is Remove the sr() function from the Page_Load also remove it from Page.IsPostBack.

Answer (score 0):

When dynamically adding controls to a page, you must add them each time the page is loaded. This should ideally be done in the Page initialization event. This is the reason your code works when you remove the !Page.IsPostBack condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is getting called two times as it is included in both page_load and page_init.
Remove it form page_load. 
Post back will always look for the changes occurred and try to reconstruct the page so your Control from code behind will get reconstructed every time.